# Cant Add user_photos items submission in facebook

Tags: facebook

I cant Add publish_actions permission for user photos Items submission in facebook,
I got Error like this,

It looks like you haven't made any API requests to access content with the user_photos permission in the last 30 days.

Please Give solution For My issue.

Comment: You need to do an api call that require that permission. Have you don't that? If so which api call did you do?